# Проблема с регулярками preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, match

Практически не разбираюсь в регулярках, пытался что-то сделать, все по нулям.

Кто может, напишите пожалуйста регулярку, которая будет пропускать все русские, английские символы, а так-же цифры и все знаки, которые есть на клав-ре (!"@№#;$%:^?&*()-_+=|/ и возможно другие)

Заранее благодарю!!!

Answer (score 1):

Проверяет, состоит ли строка из русских/английских букв, цифр, пробела и знаков c клавиатуры:

```
preg_match('/^[а-яa-z0-9!"@№#;$%:^?&*\(\)\-_+=|\/\[\]<>\s\\\\{\}\.,]*$/iu', $text);

$text = 'good>text#! да'; // 1
$text = '© copyright';  // 0
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но вот возникает проблема с такими знаками, как + \ ц е ш щ з х ф ы ч т б . л ж , } {

Comment: @DimaRRR точки, запятой, фигурных скобок и обратного слэша действительно не было в регулярке, обновил регулярку. Русские буквы должны детектиться и в этом и старом варианте - проверьте на всякий случай что модификатор `u` используется.

Comment: Знаки все стали пропускаться, кроме "+", а с буквами так и не разобрался